# geckofx , c# add event listener

Tags: c#, events, geckofx

i'm using geckofx 29. how i can call c# function on javascript event ?

i search and find this solution, but its not working:

```
public void AddEventListener_JScriptFiresEvent_ListenerIsCalledWithMessage()
        {
            string payload = null;

            browser.AddMessageEventListener("callMe", ((string p) => payload = p));

            browser.LoadHtml(
                @"<!DOCTYPE html>
                             <html><head>
                             <script type='text/javascript'>
                                window.onload= function() {
                                    event = document.createEvent('MessageEvent');
                                    var origin = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host;
                                    event.initMessageEvent ('callMe', true, true, 'some data', origin, 1234, window, null);
                                    document.dispatchEvent (event);
                                }
                            </script>
                            </head><body></body></html>");

            browser.NavigateFinishedNotifier.BlockUntilNavigationFinished();
            Assert.AreEqual("some data", payload);
        }
```

event.initMessageEvent can not execute ...

please help me

Answer (score 1):

The message event interface has been updated. The initMessageEvent method no longer exists. Look [here](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-29.0/issue/127/communication-between-c-and-javascript) at bottom of the thread. According to that body of your onload function should be:

```js
var event = new MessageEvent('callMe', { 'view': window, 'bubbles': false, 'cancelable': false, 'data': 'some data' });
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Hope this helps.